# Which library for XML files in a Delphi Cross-platform application?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm writing a FireMonkey application which must run in Windows as well in OSX. Until now I've used MSXML for my Windows apps, but of course this library is not compatible with OSX. So the question is, does Delphi XE2 include any XML library compatible with OSX, or is there a third-party XML library compatible with OSX?

Comment: is OmniXML compatible with delphi-xe2?

Comment: why would it not be? If it isn't I bet it soon will be.

Comment: Also have a look at [NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html)

Comment: See answer below about ADOM. Since ADOM is a native code implementation it should work out of the box using TXMLDocument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In unit `Xml.XMLDoc;` you have a `TXMLDocument;`
If you choose `DOMVendor := ADOM XML v4`, it's available for *Windows* **and** *OSX*.

It's directly available from the Tool palette.

Comment: `DOMVendor := ADOM XML v4` - looks like the compiler will complain ;) but +1 for ADOM (also known as Open XML)

Comment: @mjn: I agree ;o) I just wrote the needed value (I said 'choose', not 'type', so this is from the object inspector, not in the code, neither in the dfm :p).

Comment: Okay so this was back before iOS and Android support - does it work in those platforms?

Answer (score 3):

I know TNativeXML works in the unicode versions of Delphi (2009+) and I'm also pretty sure that it has no Windows API requirements.  I haven't tried compiling it with XE2 yet, but the authors site claims compatibility up to Delphi XE.

[NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html)